# Список с кнопкой "Показать еще" на ios

Tags: ios, swift

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как называется или в каком направлении копать следующее:Хочется сделать список из чего-либо, скажем, название блюд. В списке около 15 названий, когда пользователь доходит до самого низа списка, появляются следующие 15 названий или кнопка "показать еще". Желательно на языке Swift, но буду рад любому ответу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, можно реализовать метод делегата UITableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
    let rows = self.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection:0)
    switch (allPagesLoaded, rows > 5, indexPath.row >= rows - 5) {
    case (false, true, true): loadNextPage() 
    default: break
    }
}
/* грузим следующую страничку при соблюдении определенных условий, в 
данном случае это: 
если еще не все страницы загружены
всего айтемов загружено больше 5
сейчас будет показан count-5 айтем 
*/
```

Comment: Единственный вопрос, который у меня остался, это как можно прикрутить индикатор загрузки? Я думал в storyboard просто ниже cell добавить элемент indicator и поставить в свойствах анимирование, тогда этот элемент будет всегда видно при достижении нижней части экрана tableview. Но может есть более оптимизированный способ, как нибудь вторую cell прикрутить, на нее добавить indicator и скрывать/показывать эту ячейку при загрузке элементов в tableview?

Comment: я бы в tableFooterView его положил. Если речь о сториборде, просто перетащите UIView на UITableView под ячейками, его можно сделать прозрачным и положить туда UIActivityIndicatorView. Как вариант, его можно убирать и добавлять к табличке когда надо: tableView?.tableFoorterView = nil

Comment: Супер, спасибо огромное!